# Return the first word from each sentence using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

The Question is as follow:

You're given a collection of sentences.
Return a collection containing the first word of each sentence, each word is separated by a single space character.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFirstWords(IEnumerable<string> sentences)
{
    return sentences.Split(" ").Select(i => i.ToString()).Take(4);
}
```

This is what i have written so far, I am getting an empty output.

Comment: please, show your input, and the expected output

Comment: So _for each sentence_ you need to take the _first word_.  Take a look at your logic again, can you see your flaws?

Comment: `return sentences.Select(sentence => sentence.Split(" ")[0]);`

Comment: How are you getting an empty output when the code clearly doesn't even compile?

Comment: foreach the input, do the split, and yield return First()

Comment: My Input is  "this is a sentence, this is another, this is another, again" I am looking for an out put of "this , this, this, again"

Comment: That looks like a single string. Is each sentence not its own string? It looks like it should be given the method parameter.

Comment: @BlakeRogers since when are sentences delimited by commas?

Comment: @maccettura and since when words in a sentence are only delimited by a space ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but you only want the first word of each sentence:

```
return sentences.Select(s => s.Split(' ').First());
```